# What does presents mean in declaration of symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am studying some Ruby on Rails code, and found several symbols declared with **presents**, as shown below...

```rb
class MembersPresenter < Gitlab::View::Presenter::Delegated
  include Enumerable

  presents :members

  def to_ary
    to_a
  end

  def each
    members.each do |member|
      yield member.present(current_user: current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I think if you have this kind of question, you should start with studying some ruby book and then some _simple_ ruby code.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin could you recommend a good ruby book.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you are right.  have been reviewing Ruby language for last few weeks and now have a much better understanding of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question. if not, please elaborate on what exactly is unclear to you.

In line 4

```
presents :members
```

there is a method call to the `presents` class method the symbol `:members` is an argument to that method.

In line 12

```
yield member.present(current_user: current_user)
```

there is the `present` method called on each `member`. The hash `current_user: current_user` in the argument to that method.

What does that mean?

Hmm, that the class methods obviously expects a symbol (very likely it would understand a string too) and uses that to build or configure a presenter. And that the `present` instance method needs to know about the current user and the method expects the current user to be provided in an options hash or as [kwarg](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/fun-with-keyword-arguments/).

An what that really means totally depends on the codebase and what the methods do with these arguments.

Comment: [FWIW](https://gitlab.com/ninerian-gitlab/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/view/presenter/base.rb#L23-31).